# rand() give the same result in loop

Tags: c, random

I have a random function that gives numbers according to possibilities of some intervals.

```
int myrand (float array[]){ //this function gives an interval according to 
                          // possibilities


    float possib[part]; 
    int i;
    float r;
    possib[0]=array[3];
    for (i=1;i<part;i++) 
        possib[i]=possib[i-1]+array[i+3]; 
    r=(float)rand()/32767;
    printf(" r= %f ",r); //this is to check whether r is different in every run

    for(i=0;i<part;i++){
        if(r<possib[i]){
            return i;
            break;
        }
    }   

}

double myrandfinal(float array[],int n){ //this function gives a random 
    double final;  //double in the chosen interval
    final=array[n]+(((float)rand()/32767)*(array[n]-array[n-1]));
    printf("final= %f",final-array[n]); //again to check
    return final;
}

float eval() {
    float l;
    float interval[]={3.25,4.00,4.75,5.50};
    float flar[]={0.1,0.25,0.15,0.5};

        l=myrandfinal(interval,myrand(flar));
    return 3+l;

}
```

In main i have something like the following:

```
int main(){
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%f",eval()); //the evaluate function
}
```

The problem is that, when i am expecting an oputput like:

```
6.50
7.25
7.60
...
```

I get an input like:

```
6.50
6.50
6.50
...
```

Although i get different number in all checks, the result of the evaluate function is the same. In main when i just wrote

```
printf("%f",eval());
```

without the loop and execute myself for a couple times,i get different results. What would be the reason?

Sorry for my faults, i am new user, i am trying to get used to it:)

Comment: Where is `eval()` defined?

Comment: @Marievi It is defined like `myrand()` and `myrandfinal()` since it is too long and complicated, i didn't write it. It got irrelevent parts to this question.

Comment: `eval` is the function that you're asking us about, so I'd say it's entirely relevant. Please show us a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the output you get (and what you expected it to be instead).

Comment: Do not call `srand` more than once per program run.

Comment: @pmg as you can see it is called once. At the top of main.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I wrote in the simplest way. I hope it will help.

Comment: "it got irrelevent parts to this question and it is long and complicated." We're supposed to guess what's inside `eval()` that's breaking it, right? My answer is `srand(time(NULL))`. Do I get the prize?

Comment: Not tried running the code, nor analysing it in detail, but the first thing I'd try is changing `(float)rand()/32767` to `rand()/32767.0`. Even if it doesn't fix things, it's shorter.

Comment: Your claim [cannot be reproduced](http://ideone.com/s3l7Ue). Note I had to `#define part` to some arbitrary value because your example leaves it undefined. If you post code that allegedly runs, make sure it compiles and produces the result you claim it to produce.

Answer (score 0):

Out of bounds UB

```
float eval() {
    float flar[] = {0.1, 0.25, 0.15, 0.5};
    // ...
    ... myrand(flar) ...
}
```

And in the called function you try to access an inexistent element

```
int myrand (float array[]) {
    // ...
    for (i = 1; i < part; i++)
        possib[i] = possib[i - 1] + array[i + 3];
        //                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: flar[] in the original code has part+3 elements, i wrotre this one as an example. But yes, it was an out of bounds in somewhere else. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't see all relevant code, we can only guess. Two reasons why (computations using) `rand()` yield constant values:

- repeated calls to srand() with the same argument
- integer operations like division truncating the fractional part or (e.g.) yielding always 0.

Answer (score 0):

Code has a missing return path in `myrand()`

Code later uses `myrand(flar)` resulting in undefined behavior.

```
int myrand(float array[]) { //this function gives an interval according to possibilities
  float possib[part];
  int i;
  float r;
  possib[0] = array[3];
  for (i = 1; i < part; i++)
    possib[i] = possib[i - 1] + array[i + 3];
  r = (float) rand() / 32767;
  printf(" r= %f ", r); //this is to check whether r is different in every run

  for (i = 0; i < part; i++) {
    if (r < possib[i]) {
      return i;
      break;
    }
  }
  // NO RETURN VALUE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't properly seed the Linear Congruence PRNG (Pseudo Random Number Generator), you'll get always the same values. The LCPRNG is only a simple linear equation, defined as X(n+1)=(X(n)*A + B) % C, where A, B and C are constants (and X(0) is the seed).

Calling srand() with the same argument will set X(0) to the same value... NOT calling srand() will use the default X(0) everytime...

One way to get an "random" seed is to call srand() with:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```